# Want To Turn Off Drupal App So I can Run Meteor App In server

Tags: php, drupal, meteor, drupal-7, digital-ocean

I am not familiar with drupal or php. I had some developers do my website and they installed it on my digital ocean server.

However I learned how to code and redid the site to my liking, using meteor instead.

I am using 'mup' to deploy the app, and I already did this in a test domain, so it works fine. The problem is that in my real domain, I have the drupal app running, and I don't know how to turn it off.

If it was meteor I could do something like 'mup stop' and it would terminate the process on port 80. But I have been looking how to do this with drupal and the LAMP stack but I don't know how to do it.

IMPORTANT: I have an existing database that I will need in the future from the drupal app, so reseting the server is not really an option. I just want to stop it from running.

Answer (score 0):

This worked! Killed the process running on port 80 and my site was working!

```
sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:80`
```

Comment: This will only work until you restart your digitalocean droplet

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is not an app it's a website. If you want to stop the drupal website then stop apache server with command "service apache2 stop" or any equivalent command which stops your web server only.

Or else you can remove pointing your domain to the particular ip address where drupal website is hosted so that your website will not open in that domain.

Thanks